# DIY Script language garbage collection (mark & sweep)

Tags: javascript, algorithm, garbage-collection, mark-and-sweep

I'm working on some simple script language and I need a help in understanding how garbage collector works. As far as I understand it, garbage collector has two things:

1. Object pool - contains all allocated objects, can be represented as simple array. When VM creates an object (Number, String and etc) it creates appropriate instance and pushes it into the object pool:

   ```
   // init object pool
   var objectPool = [];
   // create new Number
   var numberObj = new Number(123);
   // push numberObj into objectPool
   objectPool.push(numberObj);
   // create new String
   var stringObj = new String("foo");
   // push stringObj into objectPool
   objectPool.push(stringObj);
   ```
2. Frame (not sure if it's right term) - contains references to the objects in objectPool. When we create a variable and assign a value to it, VM creates entry in the Frame. When we need to get variable value we look it in the frame. Frame can be represented as hash map:

   ```
   // init frame
   var frame = {};
   // create new String
   var stringObj = new String("bar");
   // push stringObj into objectPool
   objectPool.push(stringObj);
   // write stringObj into the frame
   frame["foo"] = stringObj;
   ```

Garbage collection (at least mark & sweep implementation), contains two steps:

1. Mark: walk through the objects that is contained in frame and mark them:

   ```
   for (var varName in frame)
     frame[varName].marked = true;
   ```
2. Sweep: walk through the objects that is contained in objectPool and remove (free) all unmarked ones:

   ```
   for (var c = 0; c < objectPool.length; c++) {
     if (!objectPool[c].marked) {
       free(objectPool[c]);
       remove(objectPool[c]);
     }
   }
   ```

Am I missing anything? Is this all looks correct?

Comment: You need to do a graph traversal to also mark the objects that are only *indirectly* reachable from the frame. This means you need to have an adjacency function that gives you, for an object, the list of objects referenced by it.

Comment: For example, if A references B, A is in the "frame", but B is not, then you need to mark B as well. You can use depth-first or breadth-first search for that

Comment: Okay, that is clear. It has to be included into "mark" step. Thanks! Anything else that I'm missing?

Comment: no, but that is the "hard" part (finding the objects referenced from another, given object). Also be sure to also include arbitrary levels of references, like A -> B -> C -> D -> E, where only A is in the frame. As I said, depth-first search is probably a good idea to go about this

Comment: yeah, devil is always in the detail, what I don't understand is that to me it looks like running garbage collector is only makes sense after something has changed in the scope, when the scope has been completely removed (for example after returning from the function) or some variable has been removed from it. Otherwise since there was no change in scope variables - no objects will be collected. Is this correct assumption?